# flink rocksdb configuration

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Given the machine infra like c5.4xlarge(16vcpu, 32g) and 16/32 task slots, what would be ideal values of `write_buffer_size`, `buffer_count`, `num_of_threads`, `block_cache_size` for rocksdb. Also setting flink managed memory to `false` is recommended or not. The [documentation](https://flink.apache.org/2021/01/18/rocksdb.html) mention that default values are not for production

Answer (score 0):

The articles you've found don't offer more specific tuning advice because we've found that the effect different parameter values have is rather application-specific. What we've tried to do is to highlight which parameters are likely to be worth paying attention to, and you should expect to do some benchmarking experiments to find good values for your use case(s).